# Improve speed of GCP SQL Failover

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying out GCPs SQL high availability options.  Is there a way to improve the fail over speed?

Attempting manual failovers through the UI takes literally over 5 minutes where mysql is completely unavailable.

I am using the smallest second generation 5.7 instances possible currently with no traffic hitting it.

It looks like it's actually stopping and starting instances.   I'm having trouble seeing how this is an option for "HA" meaning minimal downtime.